# Is there a way in knitr to evaluate inline code chunks of other languages?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

In `knitr` it is possible to use other languages in code blocks. For example, we can use:

````
```{python}
Some python code
```
````

We can use the `R` engine inline with `r some R code`

Is it possible to use other languages in **inline** code?

For example, I would like to do something like this `python some code`.

Thanks.

Comment: For now, no. It might become possible in the future (I have received a pull request quite a while ago).

Comment: Bonjour Marc-André, here is an example of the use of the listings package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414027/how-to-create-r-markdown-sections-inside-a-r-code-chunk-with-proper-code-displa/47617773#47617773

Comment: Thanks [Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie)  for your quick response. It's much appreciated. [Cedric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4494862/cedric), I will try to use the listings package but it seems much more complex than knitr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluate inline with `r shell(...)`

The shell command could be a python script that produces output for inline display. You could even pass in a shell=python3 argument.