# How to "box" the output of "summary()" in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have seen this post:
[How to create R-markdown sections inside a R code chunk? With proper code display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414027/how-to-create-r-markdown-sections-inside-a-r-code-chunk-with-proper-code-displa)

and one of the responders, Cedric, impressed me with the way he or she boxed the output of `summary()` command in R.

[image]

I understand that the user used Sweave to create such a great output.
I am curious that whether there is a way to use Knit to output to a PDF file in the similar fashion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about Sweave vs. R Markdown here. You can copy and paste the LaTeX code from [Cedric's answer that you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47617773/8386140) into a file `example.sty` and use the following R Markdown file

````
---
title: "Stack Overflow Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{example}
output: pdf_document
---


```{r boxed-summary, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:10) {
  cat("\\section{Part:", i, "}")
  cat("\\begin{lstlisting}")
  print(summary(lm(data=mtcars, mtcars[,1]~ mtcars[,i])))
  cat("\\end{lstlisting}")
  cat(paste0("$\\\\alpha$ = ", mtcars[1,i]))  
}
```
````

to create

[image]

Alternatively, you could put the LaTeX into the R Markdown document you're editing:

````
---
title: "Stack Overflow Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{listings}
    - \usepackage[usename,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    - \definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} 
    - \definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
    - \definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
output: pdf_document
---

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts that are used for the
  % code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},      % comment style
  deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  language=R,                       % the language of the code
  morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray},   % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},      % string literal style
  tabsize=2,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

```{r boxed-summary, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:10) {
  cat("\\section{Part:", i, "}")
  cat("\\begin{lstlisting}")
  print(summary(lm(data=mtcars, mtcars[,1]~ mtcars[,i])))
  cat("\\end{lstlisting}")
  cat(paste0("$\\\\alpha$ = ", mtcars[1,i]))  
}
```
````

which results in the same output.

**Attribution Note**

I want to re-emphasize here that I did not come up with the LaTeX code that creates the boxed listing; Cedric did that as mentioned above. I merely demonstrate here for the OP how to use that code in an R Markdown document rather than via Sweave as was demonstrated in the linked answer.

Comment: How about when I use libraries from R? I have some issues right now.

Comment: @JoMckenzie There shouldn't be any issue using R packages in your code. If you're running into issues doing that, my suggestion would be to open a new question.