# How to “box” the output of “summary()” of regression model in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have the next data

[image: Data]

```
modelo <-lm(Morosidad~PIB+TIIE+T.Des+Bono.3Meses+Inflacion, data=Data)
summary(modelo)
```

How I can box the output of summarry output like the next image

[image: Box]

Comment: Are you rendering to pdf or HTML?

Comment: I am rendering to pdf file

Comment: Did you try out the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58150319/3460670)? Or were you interested in something different?

Comment: Yeah I try this aproach, but doesn't work

Comment: Could you described a bit more what didn't work? Did you try the same example? Did you get an error? Or a result that wasn't what was expected?

Comment: The result wasn´t good, print the output but without the box